# Mono compatible Dependency Injection Framework

Tags: dependency-injection, mono, inversion-of-control

Which [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) frameworks are compatible (and tested) against the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) 2.4.2.3 runtime ([Release Notes](http://www.go-mono.com/archive/2.4.2.3))?

Comment: mono 2.4.2.3 is really really old!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SO question relates to using NHibernate with MONO 2.4:

[ASP.NET MVC 1 and 2 on Mono 2.4 with Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990660/asp-net-mvc-1-0-on-mono-2-4-with-fluent-nhibernate)

I have used [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity/) with Mono 2.4.2 successfully before.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7):

[Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/) is.

Comment: one of them, but also one of the best;)

Answer (score 2):

[Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) most certainly is.

Comment: Do you know if Autofac 2.5 is?

Comment: I have not upgraded, so I cannot say for certain. We're using v2.4.4.705 currently. However, considering 2.5 is highly compatible with 2.4 I would be very surprised if it was not.

Comment: Awesome.  Which version of Mono are you running?

Comment: Just checked a prod server, it's at 2.10.1. When we build a server we build mono from latest source, so I'm sure there's more than a few out there that are possibly older, too.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that over 3 years down the line I'm yet to come across an IoC Container that doesn't work on Mono.

Note: Reflection based approaches to registration will not likely work on AOT compilation based platforms such as iOS via MonoTouch.