# Castle Dynamic Proxy with Mono 2.10

Tags: c#, mono, castle-dynamicproxy

I built a class library using VS 2012/.NET 4.5 that implements lazy-loading with Castle.DynamicProxy based on [this article](http://litemedia.info/lazy-loading-property-with-castle-dynamicproxy2). It works perfectly in .NET, but will not work with Mono, despite the fact that the [documents](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy-Introduction.ashx) specifically state that DynamicProxy works with Mono 2.6 or later. One of the many exceptions I get is this:

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'Castle.Core'.
```

I'm a Mono noob, so maybe it's something obvious to a Mono expert. I'm bummed: Castle.DynamicProxy was looking really good for my current project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that Castle is incompatible with Mono.

I actually use it for some projects. I mean, I use mocking frameworks that use it. And it works beautifully.

What the Castle contributors may actually mean is that it's not guaranteed to be 100% compatible, by the simple fact that some unit tests in the Castle suite don't pass on Mono.

The sole reason why those tests don't pass is that nobody has sat down to investigate why and fix the bugs in Mono. If there are 10 failing tests, it may well be that there are 10 bugs in Mono, or just 1 that is being hit in 10 tests!

Given the pretty well experience I've had with Castle in Mono, I personally am not interested in fixing those bugs, because they must be just edge cases. I'll fix them when I hit them and I get blocked by them (like I did with https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10004), otherwise I don't have enough time unfortunately.

Morale of the story: try to fix the bug in Mono that you're hitting (instead of all of the ones that Castle are hitting), it may take you 1 or 2 days of investigation, but later you may be a happy Castle+Mono user (and opensource contributor) afterwards.

PS: Test Mono 3.x, you will have more chances of not having to investigate anything because the bug may be already fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but I don't think you read the title very carefully. I didn't say that Castle is incompatible with Mono, I said that _Castle.DynamicProxy_ is incompatible with Mono. This was confirmed by Krzysztof Koźmic, one of the key contributors to Castle.DynamicProxy, so I think I'll take his word for it! ;-)

Comment: Everywhere where I say Castle I meant Castle.DynamicProxy. Castle.DynamicProxy is the foundation of a lot of projects, such as RhinoMocks, FakeItEasy, StructureMap, Castle.Windsor... And talking about Krzysztof, here you have him saying that Castle.Windsor *is* compatible with Mono: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827157/mono-compatible-dependency-injection-framework ;)

Comment: This is a very useful answer and confirms what I suspected without having to spend hours proving it for myself.  Game on!

Comment: jfyi: tested simple proxying case for both latest Castle DynamicProxy and LinFu Dynamic Proxy under Mono 3.2.8 and they works fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind: I just got a response from one of the Castle contributors, and the documentation is wrong: Castle.DynamicProxy is NOT compatible with Mono. He said he'll change the docs, so hopefully nobody else will make the same mistake I did! Cheers.