# Convert viewmodel from C# to F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

What does the following ViewModel look like in F#?

```cs
namespace MVVMExample
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _firstName;    
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }

        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:

I am new to F# and really do want to understand how to simplify code from C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use a base `ViewModel` to inherit from and expose an interface which uses quotations so I don't need to supply string property names by hand (that is not friendly to code refactoring).

Note that according to the accepted answer to the question: [Is it possible to use CallerMemberNameAttribute in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117842/is-it-possible-to-use-callermembernameattribute-in-f) the `[<CallerMemberName>]` attribute isn't supported in F#, hence why I'm using quotations to do this.

If you define the base `ViewModel` class in C# and inherit from that class in F#, you can still get the benefits of `[<CallerMemberName>]`.  For the purposes of this answer though, I'll show you a pure F# solution.

```
type ViewModel () =
    let propertyChanged = 
        Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()
    let getPropertyName = function 
        | PropertyGet(_,pi,_) -> pi.Name
        | _ -> invalidOp "Expecting property getter expression"
    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish
    member private this.NotifyPropertyChanged propertyName = 
        propertyChanged.Trigger(this,PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    member this.NotifyPropertyChanged quotation = 
        quotation |> getPropertyName |> this.NotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then derive your specific `ViewModel` from that.

```
type NimrodViewModel() =
    inherit ViewModel()
    let mutable firstName = ""
    let mutable lastName = ""

    member this.FirstName
        with get() = firstName 
        and set(value) =
            firstName <- value
            base.notifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.FirstName @>)

    member this.LastName
        with get() = lastName 
        and set(value) =
            lastName <- value
            base.notifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.LastName @>)

    member this.GetFullName() = 
        sprintf "%s %s" (this.FirstName) (this.LastName)
```

Comment: Thanks InnerLight. One question though... What does the following notation mean? <@ ... @>

Comment: @ScottNimrod They are quotations.  They let you work with F# expressions programmatically.  See this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx

Comment: Where is "PropertyGet" defined at? I am getting a compile error.

Comment: @ScottNimrod You'll need to `open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns`

Answer (score 1):

Using [FSharp.Desktop.UI](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Desktop.UI/), it would look like this:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type ViewModel() = 
    inherit Model()

    abstract FirstName: string with get, set
    abstract LastName: string with get, set

    [<DerivedProperty>]
    member this.FullName = sprintf "%s %s" this.FirstName this.LastName
```

Instances of ViewModel would then be created by `let model: MyViewModel = ViewModel.Create()`.

By making `FullName` a property and decorating it with the `DerivedProperty`attribute, any control bound to it will automagically get a change notification when any of the properties it depends on is changed.

I'm aware that you didn't ask for an example using libraries, but I wanted to show how concise F# can be when leveraged with the right community libraries.

Comment: Is this PCL compatible?

Comment: The automation of INotifyPropertyChanged relies on Castle.Windsor, which according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090899/castle-windsor-xamarin-pcl is not PCL compatible.