# What are the differences between Mono's and Microsoft's ASP.NET implementations?

Tags: .net, asp.net, apache, mono, comparison

I'm about to launch an ASP.NET web site which will be running on a Linux server using Mono. First I would like to do some testing on my own machine. I have heard lots of info about Mono, but this is the first time I actually use it for a project.

So far, I have only deployed my applications on IIS servers. I would like to get some information about the differences between the two, but most of the questions about Mono on StackOverflow are a bit dated.

So, here are my specific questions:

- Which parts of ASP.NET 4.0 are not supported?
- Can I use NHibernate with MySQL with Mono?
- Can I use ASP.NET MVC with Mono? Is it a part of it, or its assembly needs to be in my bin directory?
- Can I use MEF with Mono? Is it a part of it, or its assembly needs to be in my bin directory?
- Is it possible to map extensionless URLs to Mono's ASP.NET on Apache?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

**EDIT:**

I know that the avaliable version of Mono may differ between Linux distributions, but it is usually possible to install the latest version on any of them. Thus, the question is about the latest available Mono version.

Comment: Latest version of mono is 2.6.7 but, for example with slicehost VPS hosting mono is available in Ubuntu 10.4 -> v2.4.4; Fedora 12 -> v2.4.2.3 and Debian 5.0 (Lenny) -> v1.9.1

Comment: volody: Valid point. In one way or another, it is possible to install the latest version for all major distros, so the question applies to the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which parts of ASP.NET 4.0 are not supported?

Full support for ASP.NET 4.0 API is [planned in version 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap).

> Can I use NHibernate with MySQL with Mono?

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990660/asp-net-mvc-1-and-2-on-mono-2-4-with-fluent-nhibernate) you [can](http://chornsokun.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/nhibernate-mono-mysql-fly-by/).

> Can I use ASP.NET MVC with Mono? Is it a part of it, or its assembly needs to be in my bin directory?

ASP.NET MVC 2 is included in Mono 2.6.7 and you don't need the assembly in your bin folder.

> Can I use MEF with Mono? Is it a part of it, or its assembly needs to be in my bin directory?

MEF should also be included in version 2.6.7, however I can't confirm it since I only tried ASP.NET MVC 2.

> Is it possible to map extensionless URLs to Mono's ASP.NET on Apache?

No idea about this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please elaborate about what parts of the ASP.NET 4.0 API are not supported yet? ALso, the extensionless URLs would be important since I prefer them. (Btw, MVC uses them by default.) Where could I educate myself about it?

Comment: I don't know if there is some reference to supported parts and to be honest I doubt that there is. Some informations might be in class status (http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Web). I would say that the best way how to find out what is supported is to try to run your application under mono. If the MVC uses them, then there shouldn't be a problem with this functionality.

Comment: thanks! Though that page says, `Assembly System.Web last updated: 100 days ago`, so it isn't relevant. :(

Comment: http://wrench.mono-project.com/builds is ASP.NET MVC running on Apache with extensionless URLs, so it's supported.